# Assembly, obtain Intel PPIN value

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, intel

Each Intel processor should provide a PPIN (Protected Processor Inventory Number) value, which is unique. I've read [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/880824/) that this value will become available in Linux starting from kernel 5.18. However, I've not found any example to directly obtain the PPIN from my own CPU through assembly code.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

I use nasm `2.15.05` on Linux `5.15.0-71-generic x86_64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This code](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1479429348-1664-2-git-send-email-tony.luck@intel.com/) suggests that you should read from MSR 0x4f.

However, `rdmsr` is a privileged instruction so you won't be able to execute it in user mode.  You'll have to write a kernel module.

Comment: It is documented in the [Intel SDM, volume 4](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/774500/335592-sdm-vol-4.pdf).  MSR 4e can be used to enable or disable access to it.